# Some built-in to pad a list in python

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

I have a list of size < *N* and I want to pad it up to the size N with a value.

Certainly, I can use something like the following, but I feel that there should be something I missed:

```
>>> N = 5
>>> a = [1]
>>> map(lambda x, y: y if x is None else x, a, ['']*N)
[1, '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is probably a better way.

Comment: I serialize the list into a tab-separated string with the fixed number of columns.

Comment: Do you mean you are doing something like '\t'.join([1,'','','',''])? Maybe you can tell us more about what you intend to implement, then we can try to come up with a idea.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: yes, _print >> a_stream, '\t'.join(the_list)_ is all I want to implement

Answer (score 269, accepted):

```
a += [''] * (N - len(a))
```

or if you don't want to change `a` in place

```
new_a = a + [''] * (N - len(a))
```

you can always create a subclass of list and call the method whatever you please

```
class MyList(list):
    def ljust(self, n, fillvalue=''):
        return self + [fillvalue] * (n - len(self))

a = MyList(['1'])
b = a.ljust(5, '')
```

Answer (score 50):

I think this approach is more visual and pythonic.

```
a = (a + N * [''])[:N]
```

Comment: This takes me half a minute to understand. The accepted answer is much more straightforward.

Comment: @RichardMöhn "pythonic" means "idiomatic". The longer you use Python, the more natural you will find this syntax.

Comment: I know what ‘pythonic’ means. And I've been using Python continuously since 2014. I still don't find your answer natural.

Comment: What makes it pythonic to construct an intermediate throw-away list?

Comment: @DylanYoung The _two_ intermediate lists don't make it pythonic nor unpythonic, neither makes it the `a` identifier nor the `=` sign. Whether mutating an object or not should depend on the concrete case, but as a general rule I tend to treat any object as immutable unless there is good reason why it should not be. If you think mutating lists is an inherently better practice or more "pythonic", it's up to you.

Comment: @NunoAndré Nothing to do with mutating anything.  You create an intermediate copy here: `a + N * ['']`.  You then throw that intermediate list out by slicing it.  You already know the length you want.  There is literally nothing more pythonic about your answer than any others. It's just poor programming practice (in any language unless you're positive that your interpreter/compiler can optimize out the duplicate list).

Comment: This answer unlike the accepted one enforces a length of `N` which may be desirable. Depends on application and that is what makes this answer useful.

Comment: @konpsych So does this one: `new_a = a + [''] * (N - len(a))`

Comment: @DylanYoung this is not the case for first  when `N < len(a)`. It is the case for the second answer you provided.

Comment: True.  I don't really like that answer either.

Comment: @konpsych Sorry, you are making assumption that OP _explicitly_ says otherwise: "I have a list of size < N and I want to pad it up to the size N with a value"

Answer (score 34):

There is no built-in function for this. But you could compose the built-ins for your task (or anything :p).

(Modified from itertool's `padnone` and `take` recipes)

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, islice

def pad_infinite(iterable, padding=None):
   return chain(iterable, repeat(padding))

def pad(iterable, size, padding=None):
   return islice(pad_infinite(iterable, padding), size)
```

Usage:

```
>>> list(pad([1,2,3], 7, ''))
[1, 2, 3, '', '', '', '']
```

Answer (score 14):

[`more-itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a library that includes a special [`padded`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.padded) tool for this kind of problem:

```
import more_itertools as mit

list(mit.padded(a, "", N))
# [1, '', '', '', '']
```

---

Alternatively, `more_itertools` also implements Python [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) including [`padnone`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.padnone) and [`take`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.take) as mentioned by @kennytm, so they don't have to be reimplemented:

```
list(mit.take(N, mit.padnone(a)))
# [1, None, None, None, None]
```

If you wish to replace the default `None` padding, use a list comprehension:

```
["" if i is None else i for i in mit.take(N, mit.padnone(a))]
# [1, '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: `mit.take(N, mit.padnone(a))` returns a list by itself.

Answer (score 8):

gnibbler's answer is nicer, but if you need a builtin, you could use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (`zip_longest` in Py3k):

```
itertools.izip_longest( xrange( N ), list )
```

which will return a list of tuples `( i, list[ i ] )` filled-in to None. If you need to get rid of the counter, do something like:

```
map( itertools.itemgetter( 1 ), itertools.izip_longest( xrange( N ), list ) )
```

Comment: I knew about _izip_longest_ but resulting the code does not look nice =)

Comment: I believe you mean `operator.itemgetter()`.  Also the `None` values needed to be replaced with `""`.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a simple generator without any build ins.
But I would not pad the list, but let the application logic deal with an empty list.

Anyhow, iterator without buildins

```
def pad(iterable, padding='.', length=7):
    '''
    >>> iterable = [1,2,3]
    >>> list(pad(iterable))
    [1, 2, 3, '.', '.', '.', '.']
    '''
    for count, i in enumerate(iterable):
        yield i
    while count < length - 1:
        count += 1
        yield padding

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pad with None instead of '', map() does the job:

```
>>> map(None,[1,2,3],xrange(7))

[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (None, 3), (None, 4), (None, 5), (None, 6)]

>>> zip(*map(None,[1,2,3],xrange(7)))[0]

(1, 2, 3, None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: To say frankly, _a+['']*(N-len(a))_ looks much clearer. Besides, it lacks casting to list. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Using iterators and taking advantage of the *default* argument for [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```py
i = iter(a)
a = [next(i, '') for _ in range(N)]
```

#### Short explanation:

Either way we want to produce `N` items. Hence the `for _ in range(N)`. Then the elements should be as much as we can from `a` and the rest `''`. Using an iterator over `a` we grab all possible elements, and when we get `StopIteration`, the *default* will be returned which is `''`.

Answer (score 4):

```
extra_length = desired_length - len(l)
l.extend(value for _ in range(extra_length))
```

This avoids any extra allocation, unlike any solution that depends on creating and appending the list `[value] * extra_length`. The "extend" method first calls `__length_hint__` on the iterator, and extends the allocation for `l` by that much before filling it in from the iterator.

Comment: More concisely, `a.extend((N-len(a))*[padding_value])` (I'm using OP notation).

Comment: Your proposal involves allocating a list, then using "extend" to append it. Mine avoids the extra allocation; no new list is created, only a generator object.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `*` [iterable unpacking operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
N = 5
a = [1]

pad_value = ''
pad_size = N - len(a)

final_list = [*a, *[pad_value] * pad_size]
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[1, '', '', '', '']
```

Answer (score 3):

To go off of kennytm:

```
def pad(l, size, padding):
    return l + [padding] * abs((len(l)-size))

>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> pad(l, 7, 0)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the padding before the list of elements

```
a[:0] += [''] * (N - len(a))
```

Adding the padding after the list of elements

```
a += [''] * (N - len(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the existing list with `np.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np
a + list(np.repeat([''], (N - len(a))))
```

Answer (score -2):

A pythonic way to pad your list with empty elements is using list comprehension.

```
        my_list = [1,2]
        desired_len = 3
        # Ensure that the length of my list is 3 elements
        [my_list.extend(['']) for _ in range(desired_len - len(my_list))]
        [my_list.pop() for _ in range(len(my_list)-desired_len )]
```

Comment: There is too much indentation in the code block. It is also recommended to print the result after the operations. Other than that, it works.