# Padding a list in python with particular value

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some built-in to pad a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438756/some-built-in-to-pad-a-list-in-python)

I have a method that will return a list (instance variable) with 4 elements.
Another method is used to assign values to the list.

But at the moment I can't guarantee that the list has 4 elements when it's asked for, so I want to fill it up with 0's.

Is there a way to fill it with 0's other than say a loop?

```
for i in range(4 - len(self.myList)):
   self.myList.append(0)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
self.myList.extend([0] * (4 - len(self.myList)))
```

This works when padding with integers. Don't do it with mutable objects.

Another possibility would be:

```
self.myList = (self.myList + [0] * 4)[:4]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> out = [0,0,0,0]   # the "template" 
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> out[:len(x)] = x 
>>> print out
[1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Assigning `x` to a slice of `out` is equivalent to:

```
out.__setitem__(slice(0, len(x)), x)
```

or:

```
operator.setitem(out, slice(0, len(x)), x)
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not create a little utility function?

```
>>> def pad(l, content, width):
...     l.extend([content] * (width - len(l)))
...     return l
... 
>>> pad([1, 2], 0, 4)
[1, 2, 0, 0]
>>> pad([1, 2], 2, 4)
[1, 2, 2, 2]
>>> pad([1, 2], 0, 40)
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = object.method()
l = l + [0 for _ in range(4 - len(l))]
```

Comment: Right. Originally I wanted to add something like `list = (list + [0 for _ in range(4)])[:4]` and then realized that it works simpler.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `list` for your var name. That will overwrite the builtin `list()`.

Comment: For me, except for the variable name as @ShawnChin said, it is the best one-line (I already have my list in a variable and post process it afterward to complete it), easily understandable. Thanks then.

Comment: You both are right, I changed my variable name now.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import repeat
self.my_list.extend(repeat(0, 4 - len(self.my_list)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.my_list.extend([0 for _ in range(4 - len(self.my_list))])
```

Comment: I like how this works with mutable objects like dicts.

Answer (score 2):

A hacky append-and-cut solution:

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> (x + [0] * 4)[:4]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Or:

```
>>> (x + [0] * (4 - len(x)))
[1, 2, 0, 0]
```