# Column_match([[1],[1,1]]) <--- how to make dimensions match with NA values?

Tags: python, numpy

Any flag for this? Please, see the intended.

```
>>> numpy.column_stack([[1], [1,2]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 296, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
```

**Input**

```
[[1],[1,2]]
```

**Intended Output**

```
[[NA,1], [1,2]]
```

**In general**

```
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],...,[n,n,n,n,n...,n]]
```

to

```
[[NA, NA, NA,..., NA,1], [NA, NA, ..., 2, 2], ...[n,n,n,n,n]]
```

where the columns may be a triangluar zero matrix initially. Yes you can understand the term NA as None. I got the triangular matrix almost below.

```
>>> a=[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]
>>> a
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> len(a)
3
>>> [aa+['']*(N-len(aa)) for
... 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> N=len(a)
>>> [aa+['']*(N-len(aa)) for aa in a]
[[1, '', ''], [2, 2, ''], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> transpose([aa+['']*(N-len(aa)) for aa in a])
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['', '2', '3'],
       ['', '', '3']], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Comment: How would NumPy know where to put the `NA`? It could be in `output[0][1]` as well.

Comment: Does [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438756/some-built-in-to-pad-a-list-in-python/3438818#3438818) help?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: `None`, what is the difference between `NA` and `None`? Zero values, nothing there. Yes the thread may become useful but I want to solve this problem this way, trying to create a triangular bottom zero matrix (zeros on the right corner).

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: actually that answer solved this question! Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

a pure numpy solution:

```
>>> lili = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
>>> y = np.nan*np.ones((4,4))
>>> y[np.tril_indices(4)] = np.concatenate(lili)
>>> y
array([[  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,   2.,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,   3.,   3.,  nan],
       [  4.,   4.,   4.,   4.]])

>>> y[:,::-1]
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   2.,   2.],
       [ nan,   3.,   3.,   3.],
       [  4.,   4.,   4.,   4.]])
```

I'm not sure which triangular array you want, there is also np.triu_indices

(maybe not always faster, but easy to read)

Answer (score 0):

column_stack adds a column to an array. That column is supposed to be a smalled (1D) array.

When I try :

```
from numpy import *
x = array([0])
z = array([1, 2])
```

if you do this :

```
r = column_stack ((x,z))
```

You'll get this :

```
>>> array([0,1,2])
```

So, in order to add a column to your first array, maybe this :

```
n = array([9])

arr = ([column_stack((n, x))], z)
```

It shows up this :

```
>>> arr
([array([[9, 0]])], array([[1, 2]]))
```

It has the same look as your "intended output"

Hope this was helpful !

Comment: not `"array([0,1,2])"` but error: `>>> x
array([0])
>>> z
array([1, 2])
>>> r = numpy.column_stack((x,z))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 296, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0`

Comment: Newest numpy from apt-get -- same err `>>> x = numpy.array([0])
>>> z = numpy.array([1,2]
... )
>>> r = numpy.column_stack((x,z))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 296, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0`