# Pair elements from two different lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
listA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
listB = ['b2', 'b4']
```

and I want to pair items in the format *any string same number*, like so:

```
listC = [('a1', None),('a2', 'b2'),('a3', None),('a4', 'b4')]
```

I´ve tried `itertools.zip_longest` but I couldn´t get what I need:

```
>>>list(itertools.zip_longest(listA, listB)
[('a1', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b4'), ('a3', None), ('a4', None)]
```

Any suggestions how to get `listC`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iter` with `next`:

```
listA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
listB = ['b2', 'b4']
l = iter(listB)
listC = [(a, next(l) if i%2 != 0 else None) for i, a in enumerate(listA)]
```

Output:

```
[('a1', None), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', None), ('a4', 'b4')]
```

Edit: pairing by trailing number:

```
import re
listA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
listB = ['b2', 'b4']
d = {re.findall('\d+$', b)[0]:b for b in listB}
listC = [(i, d.get(re.findall('\d+$', i)[0])) for i in listA]
```

Output:

```
[('a1', None), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', None), ('a4', 'b4')]
```

Comment: This will only work if listB is always a subset of listA. Maybe that's what OP wants, but wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: This was a valiant guess at what the OP wanted, but he's since posted a comment that makes it clear that you don't have the superhuman telepathy that would have been needed to answer it correctly as posted…

Comment: @abarnert can you clarify?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Read his comment on the question: He wants to pair up the strings with the same number, not skip over every other element of the shorter list.

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


list_a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
list_b = ["b2", "b4"]
```

**Code**

```
pred = lambda x: x[1:]
res = [tuple(g) for k, g in it.groupby(sorted(list_a + list_b, key=pred), pred)]
res
# [('a1',), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3',), ('a4', 'b4')]

list(zip(*it.zip_longest(*res)))
# [('a1', None), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', None), ('a4', 'b4')]
```

---

**Details**

A flat, sorted list is grouped by the numbers of each string and yields grouped `res`ults according to the predicate.  Note, if strings start with a *single* letter, the predicate should work for any digit, `"a1"`, `"b23"`, `"c132"`, etc.  If you are willing, you might also consider a trailing number regex as seen in [@Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49703108/4531270).

As you discovered, [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) pads `None` to shorter sub-groups by default.

**See Also**

- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438756/some-built-in-to-pad-a-list-in-python) for more ideas on padding iterables
- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby/45873519#45873519) on how to use `itertool.groupby`
- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside) on natural sorting for a more robust predicate

Comment: That `len(max(res))` is the length of the last tuple, not the length of the longest tuple; you need to add a `key=len` in there.

Comment: Also, you don't need a `lambda` here; I think `itemgetter(1)` may be a little clearer to a novice (or at least give them something they can look up), as well as being a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Thank you @abarnert.  The `len` keyword is subtle and insightful.  I am still working on parsing digits, so I'm thinking `lambda` might be more flexible for now.

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely advantages to lambda for flexibility. If the OP comes back and says "It doesn't work for c27", you just need to change `x[1]` to `x[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with a ternary statement for this:

```
listA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
listB = ['b2', 'b4']

listB_set = set(listB)
listC = [(i, 'b'+i[1:] if 'b'+i[1:] in listB_set else None) for i in listA]

# [('a1', None), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', None), ('a4', 'b4')]
```

However, for clarity and performance, I would consider separating numeric and string data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dict approach:

```
listA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
listB = ['b2', 'b4']

final_list={}
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(listA,listB):
    data,data1=list(i[0]),list(i[1])
    if data[1]==data1[1]:
        final_list[i[0]]=i
    else:
        if i[0] not in final_list:
            final_list[i[0]]=(i[0],None)

print(final_list.values())
```

output:

```
[('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', None), ('a4', 'b4'), ('a1', None)]
```