# Is there any easy way to add elements in lists in a list to make all lists in a list has a same number of element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Honestly, I didn't find out for this question cuz... I don't know how to search or google it. So it might be the basic problem, but if anyone can helps me, I would really appreciate it.

So, the problem is... basically from the Index Error: list index out of range, which was raised while I tried to make a list of lists to excel file.

Apparently, the error raised cuz some of my list has 8 elements while some of my list has less elements than those.

for example:

```
results = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

and I tried to convert it as excel with xlsxwriter with this code:

```
for row in range(len(results)):
    for col in range(len(results[0])):
        sheet.write(row, col, results[row][col])
```

And now you know why the error was raised.

So, what I want to do about it is adding some blank elements to the less-element-having list to make all list has a same number of elements

like this:

```
results = [[1,2,3,'','','','',''],[1,2,3,4,'','','','',],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

Thanks for your attention and helps in advance!

Comment: Why not just loop over the available elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some built-in to pad a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438756/some-built-in-to-pad-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `zip` with `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
import itertools

list(zip(*itertools.zip_longest(*results, fillvalue='')))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, '', '', '', '', ''),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, '', '', '', ''),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Can I ask what does * means with itertools and results? Sorry for the rookie question

Comment: @JeongInKim Sure you can! `*` in this case _unpacks_ the iterables. In other words, `*results` becomes lists instead of single list of lists. [Reading the official document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) may help you have better understanding of it :)

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks Chris! You totally taught me to understand it ! I'll check the official document as well! Thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, hers's one:

```
results = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
m = max(len(l) for l in results)
results = [l + ['']*(m-len(l)) for l in results]
```

Comment: Thanks Julien !
I thought making this code would be complex and took long lines in my head xD

Obviously, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change the data to suit the loop it would be better to change the loop.

The [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is helpful for this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

results = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]

for row, row_data in enumerate(results):
    for col, data in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's another approach! I'll keep enumerate() function for the next time. It seems really helpful as you said!